# Windows Form Combobox.Items.Clear() leaves empty slots

Tags: winforms, combobox, items

I am working on a Windows Form that has multiple comboboxes.  Depending on what is chosen in the first combobox determines what items are filled into the second combobox.  The issue I am running into is if I choose ChoiceA in ComboBox1, ComboBox2 is clear()ed, then is filled with ChoiceX, ChoiceY, and ChoiceZ.  I then choose ChoiceB in ComboBox1, ComboBox2 is clear()ed, but there are no choices to add to ComboBox2, so it should remain empty.  The issue is, after choosing ChoiceB, there's a big white box with three empty slots in ComboBox2.  So, basically, however many items are cleared N, that's how many empty slots show up after choosing ChoiceB.

This might be a tad confusing, I hope I explained it well enough.

-- EDIT Adding Code, hope it helps clear things up.  BTW, mainItemInfo is another "viewmodel" type class.  It interfaces back into the form to make updates.

```
private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownItem item = (DropDownItem)cmbType.SelectedItem;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Text))
        {
            cmbBrand.Enabled = true;
            btnAddBrand.Enabled = true;

            mainItemInfo.FillBrands(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Type", item.Text } });
            mainItemInfo.SyncBrands(this);
        }
    }

public void FillBrands(Dictionary<string, string> columnsWhere)
    {
        // Clear list
        Brands.Clear();
        // Get data
        StorageData storage = new StorageData(File.ReadAllLines(ItemsFilePath));
        // Fill Brands
        foreach (string type in storage.GetDistinctWhere(columnsWhere, "Brand"))
        {
            Brands.Add(type, new DropDownItem(type, type));
        }
    }

public void SyncBrands(IPopupItemInfo form)
    {
        form.ClearcmbBrand();
        var brands = from brand in Brands.Keys
                     orderby Brands[brand].Text ascending
                     select brand;
        foreach (var brand in brands)
        {
            form.AddTocmbBrand(Brands[brand]);
        }
    }

public void AddTocmbBrand(DropDownItem brand)
    {
        cmbBrand.Items.Add(brand);
    }

    public void ClearcmbBrand()
    {
        cmbBrand.Items.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: I confess to being confused, add the code in the eventhandler for combo 1 to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the extra space.  I changed the Add and Clear methods to:

```
public void AddTocmbModel(DropDownItem model)
    {
        cmbModel.Items.Add(model);
        cmbModel.DropDownHeight = cmbModel.ItemHeight * (cmbModel.Items.Count + 1);
    }

    public void ClearcmbModel()
    {
        cmbModel.Items.Clear();
        cmbModel.DropDownHeight = cmbModel.ItemHeight;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply, you can add an item then clear the combobox again:

```
   cmbBrand.Items.Clear();
   cmbBrand.Items.Add(DBNull.Value);
   cmbBrand.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should able to set the datasource of listbox2 to null to clear it, then set it again with the new data.

So, in pseudo-code, something like:

```
ItemSelectedInListBox1()
{
    List futureListbox2Items = LoadOptionsBaseOnSelectedItem(item)

    Listbox2.Datasource = null
    Listbox2.Datasource = futureListBox2Items
}
```

That should refresh the list of items displayed in Listbox2 with no white spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work either.  I am still getting the extra empty slots.

Comment: Hm. Sorry that didn't help. The only thing I could think of then is that the initial list of items sent in has some empty values.

Comment: Well, to make sure, I put a breakpoint on the foreach line in public void SyncBrands(IPopupItemInfo form) where it adds to the combobox after it is cleared.  It actually does not add anything.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to call `.Items.Clear()` first then set `Datasource` to `null`. Doing it in that order got rid of the empty white lines